# Returning values from T-SQL block of code in python / pyodbc / sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, t-sql, sqlalchemy

I need to execute a block of T-SQL code from python through pyodbc:

```
DECLARE @result table(logTime datetime, value float)
    
/* ...
 do some processing and fill the @result table 
   ... */                
SELECT * FROM @result
```

And I execute it in python like so:

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
   
    
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?dsn=mydb&trusted_connection=yes'")
conn = engine.connect()

sql = f"""
DECLARE @result table(logTime datetime, value float)
    
/* ...
 do some processing and fill the @result table 
   ... */                
SELECT * FROM @result
"""

info = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

However, where it works for executing single statements or store procedures, this one results in:

> ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

How do I get the result from such a T-SQL code block? Unfortunately, I don't have the rights on the database to create a stored procedure, it would be easy if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

adding

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

at the beginning of the block solves it :)